# PHP table Pagination how to put $output into my html table?

Tags: php, html, pagination, html-table, echo

I can't put the

```
echo $output['description'].'<br />';
```

into html table...

as I want my table to be look like below:

```
<br />
<tr> Des: ['description']</tr><br />
<tr> Name: ['name']</tr><br />
<tr> Remark: ['remark']</tr><br />
```

```
$resultsPerPage = 10;
    $startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
    $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products'));
    $totalPages = ceil($numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage");

    while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

        echo $output['description'].'<br />';


            echo $output['name'].'<br />';
            echo $output['remark'].'<br />';

    echo '<a href="?page=1">First</a>&nbsp';

if($page > 1)
    echo '<a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">Back</a>&nbsp';

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
{
    if($i == $page)
        echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>&nbsp';
    else
        echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp';
}

if ($page < $totalPages)
    echo '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next</a>&nbsp;';

echo '<a href="?page='.$totalPages.'">Last</a>';
?>
```

Comment: HI Malachi, I would like to add the word "Des" in front of the echo $output['description'].'<br />';......how can I do that?

Comment: you are also missing Brackets and Table Element tags

Comment: did you get it working?  please accept an answer, or upvote an answer, and let us know if you got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo 'Des' . $output['description'] . '<br />';
```

If you want to style things you can try this:

```
echo '<div id="des">Des</div><div class="description">' . $output['description'] . '</div>';
```

or

```
echo '<div id="des">Des</div><div class="description">';
echo $output['description'];
echo '</div>';
```

I prefer the first one

Comment: Yeah! It works! But if I wanna add font size, font type or font color, what should I do?

Comment: echo '<div id="des">Des</div><div class="description">' . $output['description'] . '</div>';
then you have to style the div-containers.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following code

1. Added braces, to clarify the scope of code.
2. Saved all echo into a variable by appending to previous value, and outputting that variable in end.
3. Typed cast your `numberOfRows` variable to float, just to ensure less buggy.

   ```
   $resultsPerPage = 10;
   $startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
   $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`"));
   $totalPages = ceil((float)$numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT {$startResults}, {$resultsPerPage}");

   while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

       $html = '<span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;">
                   Des: ' . $output['description'].'</span><br />';
       $html .= 'Name: ' . $output['name'].'<br />';
       $html .= 'Remark: ' . $output['remark'].'<br />';
       $html .= '<a href="?page=1">First</a>&nbsp';

       if($page > 1) {
           $html .= '<a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">Back</a>&nbsp';

           for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {

               if($i == $page) {   $html .= '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>&nbsp';    } 
               else {              $html .= '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp';  }

           }

           if ($page < $totalPages) {
               $html .= '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next</a>&nbsp;';
           }
       }

       $html .= '<a href="?page='.$totalPages.'">Last</a>';
       echo $html;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot..sorry but if i would like to insert test before $output['description'], what should I do? And also I would like to change its color and font size as well...could you pls teach me..

Comment: @SoKim, could you please explain the word insert? Do you mean add test as in more HTML or make SQL inserts before $output['description'] .

Comment: hi there, I would like to add the text "des" before the $output['description']...and would like to change the font bigger and font type as well...any hint?

Comment: @SoKim, have changed the code near `$output['description']`, kindly check.

Comment: @SoKim, HTML elements styling can be acheived by CSS. this is the best section to start as beginner. `http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp`

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to put the braces for the while statement, then please give some details of how the result of the query looks like :) Or why you can't put that "echo".

If you want to add that "Des" in front, then you will do something like this:

`echo "Des: ". $output["description"]. "<br />";`

Answer (score 0):

if you want something in front of the data just add it to the echo.
or give some more echo statements.

```
echo 'des: ';
echo $output['description'].'<br />';
```

or

```
echo 'Des' . $output['description'] . '<br />';
```

like in Kathi's answer

Comment: Thanks! It works! But if I wanna add font size, font type or font color, what should I do?

Comment: add some HTML tags with and some CSS styling

Comment: if this is what did it for you please upvote and accept an answer